# Access AWS services from Apache Nifi running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-nifi, amazon-iam

I have a Nifi instance running on an EC2 machine and I am trying to access a restricted s3 bucket. Because generating access keys manually is not recommended, I want to give the machine the proper IAM role for accessing the outside bucket.

I gave the EC2 machine a role which seems to work for every application *except* for Nifi. Is there some special config I need to set for Nifi to not use manual access keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue myself. It turns out that if you set the "Use Default Credentials" flag to true it will use whatever permissions are given to the IAM user associated with the machine.

Comment: Note that the "Use Default Credentials" isn't available from the various processors directly (ex. FetchS3Object). You'll need to add a "AWS Credentials Provider service" controller and set the value in there, then update your processor(s) to use it.

Comment: Hey @Ethan McCue. I'm also facing same issue. could be please help me. what is assumed role session name you have provided or where you refered? Because i got error like AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID

Answer (score 1):

You can use both, aws credentials or IAM policy.
If you use AWS credentials with the AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService, you need to provide an Access Key and Secret Key, and then you can set the proper permissions to this key.

[image]

If you use an IAM policy, you need to create a Role, asign this role to the NiFi machine and then asign a policy to this role with the S3 permissions you need.

Comment: So is it impossible to use the IAM role like other applications?

Comment: @EthanMcCue Correct me if I'm wrong. AWS IAM user comes with an access key and secret key. You have to provide the IAM user's access key and secret key here in the configuration.

Comment: That is not true. An IAM Role doesn't have a user visible set of access keys.

Comment: The permissions can administer using IAM, I did it but can't remember the details right now.

Comment: "you need to provide Access Key and Secret Key" as Ethan mentioned you don't need to do this and this goes against AWS S3 best practices from what I've read. For example, once you have create the role and associated with a particular host machine, you won't need to provide any keys in the nifi properties. I've confirmed that this works.

Comment: Not sure if this post is dead, but how would you create a role associated with a host machine..? For instance, our nifi instance is on prem, and using access keys to authenticate, but would like to move to IAM Service role of some type.. Any thoughts ?